# How to share an object instance among spiders running on scrapyd

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy, scrapyd

I need to share one common object instance among crawlers / spiders running on scrapyd.
The best scenario would be to hook the object's methods on each spider's signals, something like

```
ext = CommonObject()
crawler.signals.connect( ext.onSpiderOpen,   signal = signals.spider_opened )
crawler.signals.connect( ext.onSpiderClose,  signal = signals.spider_closed )

etc..
```

where *CommonObject* would be instantiated and initialized **only once** and expose its methods to all running crawling processes / spiders (I don't mind using singleton for this purpose).

Based on my research I understand I have two options:

1. Run all spiders / crawlers within one *CrawlerProcess*, where also the *CommonObject* would be instantiated.
2. Run one spider / crawler per *CrawlerProcess* (default scrapy(d) behavior), instantiate the *CommonObject* somewhere in the reactor and perhaps access it remotely using *twisted.spread.pb*.

Questions:

1. Are there any CPU utilization penalties (is CPU utilized less effectively) using the first option over letting scrapyd to manage the processes (which is the second option)? Is *CrawlerProcess* capable of running more crawlers **in parallel** (not sequentially)? How would you schedule further spiders during run-time within the same *CrawlerProcess*? (I understand *CrawlerProcess.start()* is blocking.)
2. I am not advanced enough to implement the second option (actually not sure whether it's viable option at all). Is there anybody who would draw a sample implementation?
3. Perhaps I am missing something and there is another way of doing this?